# scala string substitution of templates

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I know that scala has the string interpolation where you can do things like:

```
s"${firstName} ${lastName}"
```

The nice thing about it is that there are less chances of screwing up compared to string.format where I can screw up the arguments like

```
"%s %s".format(lastName, firstName)
```

Is there a way to keep the template as a variable and evaluate for multiple values of firstName and lastName? Something along the lines of:

```
val template = "${firstName} ${lastName}"
persons.map{case(firstName, lastName) => 
//substitute template here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse pattern then easy way would be create a function around it

```
def format(firstName: String, lastName:String) = s"${firstName} ${lastName}"

persons.map{case(firstName, lastName) =>
  format(firstName,lastName)
}
```

the long way would be to parse a pattern into `StringContext` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643036/scala-runtime-string-interpolation-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

How about use **Regex** to extract data, like:

```
  val R = "(\\w+) (\\w+)".r
  val (firstName, lastName) = "hello world" match {
    case R(a, b) => (a, b)
  }

  println(firstName)
  > hello
  println(lastName)
  > world
```

Find more:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html